# PC not listing video and audio from media server

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, media-server

I have set up a small media server PC, and I have configured my windows media player to stream to other devices, I am able to pick up the server on the network from another PC, but for some reason, the video and music showing in the player on the server, do not show up on the media player on my other PC.

I added the video and music folders on my external to their respective libraries on the server PC, it has indexed everything and it is showing up fine on the server PC's media player, but not on any other connected PC, it only shows the sample music, pictures and videos on those.

Any idea why this could be happening, and how I could possibly fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From an elevated command prompt, try `mklink /d c:\shares\music \\server\music` (adapt as required).

Now add `c:\shares\music` to the Music Library and see if it shows up in WMP?

Answer (score 0):

Check if uPnP is enabled on the network

Comment: uPnP seems to be enabled.

Comment: try connecting the media server directly to another PC with an ethernet cable and check if it works .

Answer (score 0):

Check if the permissions of the music and video folder on the server PC are set correctly, so that the files can be accessed from another PC. You may even need to add read privileges for the **Everyone** group to those folders.